# Equivalent of Haskell List comprehension example in Python

Tags: python, list, haskell, list-comprehension

I was wondering if the following `List comprehension` example from [learnyouahaskell.com](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out) can be duplicated in `Python`:

```
[ if x < 10 then "BOOM!" else "BANG!" | x <- xs, odd x]
```

I tried around with something like this, but couldn't get a equivalent to the `else` path to work in Python's List Comprehension:

```
["BOOM!" for x in range(7,13) if x < 10] # else "BANG!"
```

Comment: you can write 
["BOOM!" if x < 10  else "BANG!" for x in range(7,13) ]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not filtering, but a ternary operator that you put in the *yield* part of the list comprehension. There is however a filter: the `odd x` part, you thus should add a filter `if x % 2 == 1` at the end of the list comprehension:

```
["BOOM!" if x < 10 else "BANG!" for x in range(7,13) if x % 2 == 1]
```

In Python this gives us:

```
>>> ["BOOM!" if x < 10 else "BANG!" for x in range(7,13) if x % 2 == 1]
['BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BANG!']
```

Which is equivalent in Haskell:

```
Prelude> [ if x < 10 then "BOOM!" else "BANG!" | x <- [7 .. 12], odd x]  
["BOOM!","BOOM!","BANG!"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the if-else as the expression that is evaluated by the comprehension

```
['BOOM!' if x < 10 else 'BANG!' for x in range(7, 13)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move it like this:

```
["BOOM!" if x < 10 else "BANG!" for x in range(7,13) ]
```